# Groovy AST INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase vs SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS

Tags: groovy

This piece of code works in my visitor in the SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS phase but not in the INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase. It looks like I am not able to use the constructor call. If I change the constructor instead to Arrays.asList() it seems to compile. Any help is appreciated

```
val codeBlock = GeneralUtils.block()

// Declare the futures list
val arrayListNode = ClassHelper.make(ArrayList::class.java)
val variable = "myVariable"
val variableDeclaration = GeneralUtils.varX(variable, arrayListNode)
val asListExpression = GeneralUtils.ctorX(arrayListNode)
val variableStmt = GeneralUtils.declS(variableDeclaration, asListExpression)
codeBlock.addStatement(variableStmt)

//
// Set the codeBlock back to the closure
closure.code = codeBlock
```

In the instruction selection phase, the error I get is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: size==0
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.getTopOperand(OperandStack.java:672)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:318)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.sc.StaticTypesBinaryExpressionMultiTypeDispatcher.evaluateEqual(StaticTypesBinaryExpressionMultiTypeDispatcher.java:142)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitDeclarationExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:637)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seemed to work.

```
// Declare the futures list
val arrayListNode = ClassHelper.make(ArrayList::class.java)
val variable = "myVariable"
val variableDeclaration = GeneralUtils.varX(variable, arrayListNode)
val asListExpression = GeneralUtils.ctorX(arrayListNode)

// Look for the arraylist constructor in the node
val arrayNodeConstructorMethod = arrayListNode.getDeclaredConstructor(arrayOf())
asListExpression.setNodeMetaData(StaticTypesMarker.DIRECT_METHOD_CALL_TARGET, arrayNodeConstructorMethod)

val variableStmt = GeneralUtils.declS(variableDeclaration, asListExpression)
codeBlock.addStatement(variableStmt)

//
// Set the codeBlock back to the closure
closure.code = codeBlock
```